# Search scoring doesn't make sense

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm using default scoring on my search index.  The index is based on PDF content stored in Azure blob storage.  The scoring results don't make sense to me based on my understanding of default scoring:

> The search score is computed based on statistical properties of the data and the query. Azure Search finds documents that include the search terms in the query string (some or all, depending on searchMode), ***favoring documents that contain many instances of the search term***. The search score goes up even higher if the term is rare across the data corpus, but common within the document. The basis for this approach to computing relevance is known as TF-IDF or term frequency-inverse document frequency.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/search/index-add-scoring-profiles)

If I enter the search phrase 'medical examination' I find three results scored as follows:

```
Document #1 - "Score":0.0013401981
Count of term "medical" = 2X
Count of term "examination" = 7X

Document #2 - "Score":0.001295743
Count of term "medical" = 5X
Count of term "examination" = 4X

Document #3 - "Score":0.00069354917
Count of term "medical" = 11X
Count of term "examination" = 2X
```

The first 2 results are similar WRT overall score, though they have variations in how frequently these words appear in the body of the PDFs.  The third result, however, has the lowest score, yet highest overall frequency of words.

Can anybody explain these results?

Comment: What is the count of the phrase "medical examination" in each of these documents?

Comment: The phrase "medical examination" appears only once and that's in the document #2.